# Which Dll or OCx contains the implementation for VB 6.0 controls

Tags: user-controls, vb6

I have "ocx" (Developed in VB 6.0)  which has various usercontrols as below,

1. Usercontrol internally has VB 6.0 textbox
2. Usercontrol internally has VB 6.0 Label
3. Usercontrol internally has VB 6.0 Combobox
4. Usercontrol internally has VB Tree control for which I am reffering MSCOMCT2.OCX

Declared as:

```
Object={86CF1D34-0C5F-11D2-A9FC-0000F8754DA1}#2.0#0; MSCOMCT2.OCX
```

In Windows 7 64 bit machine the 4th control is getting loaded properly, But not first 3 controls are not getting loaded.

What ocx or dll is required for VB 6.0 controls to load?

Comment: What error are they failing with?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install and register the full set of [vb6 runtimes](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417) into the 32-bit system folder (`C:\Windows\SysWow64`). Note that on Vista+, these are already installed and protected against being replaced.